# Issue adding an inherited object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I am working on a small project using Entity Framework. I have a Group entity and a MissionTrip:Group entity (and also a SmallGroup:Group entity but that shouldn't be necessary information). I am using Table-Per-type inheritance set up analogously to the inheritance in [this blog post by Muhammed Mosa](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-2.aspx).

I can't save a MissionTrip to the GroupSet using AddObject("GroupSet", missionTrip) or AddToGroupSet(missionTrip).

The MissionTrip object I am trying to save is a new, valid MissionTrip. The AddObject method does not throw any exception or give any indication that it did not work yet the object is not persisted to the database.

I am able to save un-hierarchical objects to the database using the exact same method but with correct results.

Let me know if more information would be helpful, any help would be appreciated

**Edit**
If it clarifies anything I am using the MySQL Data Provider.
 I am able to retrieve MissionTrip typed objects from the GroupSet but am unable to add them. I cannot save instances of the other inherited type (SmallGroup) either.

Comment: What you are doing should work. So it sounds a lot like there is some sort of mapping problem. Are you sure you've got that right?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem wasn't related to inheritance at all. I was calling SaveChanges from a different repository than the one that was tracking the change. I'm still pretty new to EF.